# Too many redirect in AMP version

Tags: wordpress, redirect, amp-html

I have website/blog. I face one issue of redirecting.

I build my website through WordPress.

When I enable mobile redirection option for perticular post and when I publish it, after that I load it in mobile but this will show- medicojuice redirect you too many time.

Here medicojuice is my domain name.

When I disable redirecting option to perticular post then this url working normally and load with non-AMP version.

In post setting there are two option-one is page AMP and second is mobile redirection.

Well when I enable first option and **enable** also second option then this error show.

But when I enable first option and **disable** second option, then this problem goes away. Only one thing will happen that it load in **non-AMP version**.

But I need it in AMP version.

If you solve this error then this will really really help me.

Comment: Which plugin you are using?

Comment: AMP in red color icon.

Comment: AMP for WP? maybe possibly related to the cache issue ask their support forum check by disabling javascript in browser

Comment: check if you are using WP Super Cache and Autoptimize plugins those two are known for that kind of behavior, Also try the official AMP plugin version ( blue color icon )